# bash_profile cannot fetch node version

Tags: bash, macos

In my `~/.bash_profile` I have

```
export SBT_OPTS="${SBT_OPTS} -Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node -Dsbt.jse.command=$(which node)"
```

and also have node in

```
$ which node
/Users/alijy/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node
```

But when I start a fresh terminal window, node is not found/replaced in the script, and I get

```
echo $SBT_OPTS
-Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node -Dsbt.jse.command=
```

On the terminal, I tried

```
$ export SBT_OPTS="-Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node -Dsbt.jse.command=$(which node)"
$ echo $SBT_OPTS
-Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node -Dsbt.jse.command=/Users/alijy/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin/node
```

which works fine and finds node.

What is wrong with my bash_profile script?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you adding `/Users/alijy/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin` to `PATH`?

Comment: It will be better to directly add the path of your node in the export command, instead of using `which node`. `which` command checks the PATH variable, which you are defining inside your `.bash_profile`

Comment: ...for that matter, searching the PATH is what happens by default if you provide a unqualified command name, so if you had a PATH that would make `which` work, you could just use `-Dsbt.jse.command=node` and wouldn't *need* `which` in the first place.

Comment: Anyhow -- find the place in your dotfiles where you set up `nvm`. Move the `SBT_OPTS` assignment below it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when your export SBS_OPTS is executed, it doesn't have the information about 'node'. That means PATH for node is not loaded till that time and that's the reason 'which node' command fails.

Open terminal and run

```
echo $PATH
```

You'll see /Users/alijy/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin in there

Now find where its getting added to the PATH variable. For that, scan your .bash_profile and .bashrc files. Whichever file it is, make sure it gets loaded before your "export SBT_OPTS= " command.

Comment: I had NVM_DIR being exported couple of lines below SBT_OPTS. Moved that up and all worked. Thanks.